Help with R. Pink complete lecture notes of "Finite group schemes". Theorem 12.2
I'm an undergrad and I'm doing an assignment on Richard Pink's lectures notes on finite group schemes.
I kinda understood anything until this theorem comes (I skipped the motivation because my "supervisor" advised me to).
Theorem 12.2. The functor $G_{k^\text{sep}}\to G(k^\text{sep})$ defines an equivalence from the category of finite étale group schemes over $k$ to the category of continuous finite $\mathbb Z[\operatorname{Gal}(k^\text{sep}/k)]$-modules.
In the proof: (...) Proposition 12.1 implies that the
latter is equivalent to the category of continuous finite Galois-modules.
The fact is that Pink defines two different things with $R[G]$ with $G$ group. One is the free algebra over the group $G$, and the other is the twisted group ring over a Galois group, the latter was shown only on fields. The thing is that even thought I proved proposition 12.1 I don't know what a "continuous galois module" is.
My suspect is that the functor that sends $G_{k^\text{sep}}$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}(k^\text{sep}),G)$ (which holds a group structure) is a "continuous Galois module" whatever that means.
Also looking on the internet I think it's related to Galois representations even if I don't know what it means.

Please use MathJax for writing mathematics. I edited the post to the best of my knowledge, but please make sure I did not change the meaning.

I will try clearing up the terminology you are unfamiliar with.
A Galois representation is a group representation of a Galois group. Group representation, in their naive form, are just group homomorphisms from a group $G$ into the general linear group of a vector space $V$. In the finite-dimensional case, this gives you a way of interpreting your group as a group of matrices, hence making the methods of linear algebra very explicitly applicable.
If you fix a base field $K$, you can define $K$-representation, that is, group representation on $K$-vector spaces. For that, you consider the group algebra $K[G]$ which is the free $K$-algebra generated by $G$. Then a $K$-representation is equivalently given by $K[G]$-module, and you can translate representation-theoretic concepts into module-theoretic ones.
Making an educated guess, a notion twisted group algebra I am familiar with is generally constructed from a given ring $A$ and a group action $\sigma\colon G\to\operatorname{Aut}(A)$, sometimes denoted by $A\rtimes G$. As an $A$-module, it is just the group algebra $A[G]$ (i.e. the free $A$-module with basis the elements of $G$) but its multiplication is given by $ag\cdot bh=a\sigma(b)gh$. If you choose the trivial action for $\sigma$, this recovers the group algebra construction for general rings $A$.
Given the above, we also refer to modules corresponding to Galois representations as Galois modules. These are modules over the group algebra associated to the Galois group. Here, Galois modules refers more explicitly to the case of modules over the group algebra $\mathbb Z[G]$, which also leads to group and Galois cohomology, but I digress. The finite part in the theorem then probably refers to some finiteness condition imposed on the given modules (e.g. finite generation).
The continuity part is tied to the fact that (infinite) Galois group admit a natural topology, called the Krull topology. In the case of finite extensions, this can be ignored, since the Krull topology is then discrete. However, in the infinite case this topological perspective plays a crucial role (for instance, the fundamental theorem of Galois theory only extends as a correspondence between subextensions and closed subgroups). Naturally, a Galois module is a Galois representation into, say, a topological abelian group, which is continuous with respect to the Krull topology on the Galois group. The most natural examples would be the extension field as additive group as well as its multiplicative subgroup for topological fields (or alternatively with some discrete topology, but I do not remember the details right now).
You are looking a the $k^\text{sep}$-points of a group scheme. Thus, you may act on its coordinates with the (separable) absolute Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(k^\text{sep}/k)$. Since Pink assumes group schemes to be commutative, this gives you the desired $\operatorname{Gal}(k^\text{sep}/k)$-module structure, that is, the structure of an $\mathbb Z[\operatorname{Gal}(k^\text{sep}/k)]$-module.

Thaks, you answered completely to all my doubts.

@MatteoMunafò Glad to help! Make sure to accept the answer if you have no further question. If there is something else I can help with, just ask (but maybe in another post) :)
